# Superscript R squared for legend

Tags: r, legend

I want to write a R-squared term for my legend but I do not know how. Could someone help me please?
My legend syntax is:

```
legend(2,10, c("BW (MPE=3%, R-squared=0.77)", 
       "MY (MPE=5%, R-squared=0.80)", pch=c(2,3))
```

I would liek to express R-squared as R2 as we normally have in the text.

Answer (score 12):

It will work if you combine `bquote` and `as.expression`:

```
plot(1:10)
legend(2, 10, c(as.expression(bquote("BW (MPE = 3%," ~ R^2 ~ "= 0.77)")),
                as.expression(bquote("MY (MPE = 5%," ~ R^2 ~ "= 0.80)"))), 
       pch=c(2,3))
```

[image]

Comment: It is helpful to know that `as.expression( bquote(... ), bquote( ...) )` might succeed if one needed to "import" values that exist outside the call.

Comment: what if your r-square value was stored as an object, `r.sq`, and the value of `r.sq` is 0.80. How can you drop this into the `as.expression(bquote...` call above?

Comment: @colin try this: `bquote(R^2 == .(r.sq))`

Answer (score 9):

This is less complex than using `c( as.expression ( bquote...`  multiple times:

```
plot(1:10)
legend(2, 10, expression("BW (MPE = 3%," ~ R^2 ~ "= 0.77)",
                 "MY (MPE = 5%," ~ R^2 ~ "= 0.80)"), 
        pch=c(2,3))
```

It is useful to understand that the `expression` function is really a way to make lists of expressions and that commas are therefore reserved as separators for that process. This means you cannot have a "naked" comma in something you want to be inside one of the distinct elements. The commas immediately after the `%`-signs are protected from parsing by the quotes. This could fully plotmath()-ified  with:

```
plot(1:10)
legend(2, 10, expression(BW * list(MPE == 3*'%',
                                   R^2 == 0.77),
                         MY * list( MPE == 5*'%',
                                   R^2 == 0.80)
                         ), 
       pch=c(2,3))
```

That way the only character needing special attention is the '%'-sign because `plotmath()` uses that character to delimit items in the list of 'special' math tokens. See `?plotmath` for the full list.

Comment: +1 This is a nice solution. The lower code does not display the parentheses. I suppose, you want `expression("BW (" * list(MPE == 3*'%', R^2 == 0.77) * ")", ...`.

Comment: I suppose your suggestion is nicer than adding `group( "(", ... , ")" )`. I try to avoid using quotes inside expressions if possible, but sometimes it's just more economical to use them.

Comment: What if your R-squared value is stored in a variable, lets say instead of `0.77`, you need to print out the value stored in variable `a`.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire: I don't see a lot of connection to the original question. If you have a new questions and cannot find a useful answer with searching SO and the web, then post another question with a [MCVE]