# R-squared and n in plot legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I would like a plot legend to contain both the R-squared value, as well as another value (the number of datapoints, *n*, in this case, but it's not specifically important). I'd like R-squared in the format *R*^2 =, where R is italicised, and 2 is superscript.

Adding R-squared in this way on its own can be achieved on the following example using `bquote`

```
DF <- data.frame(VAR1=rnorm(100), VAR2=rnorm(100))
with(DF, plot(VAR1, VAR2))
fit <- lm(VAR2 ~ VAR1, data=DF)
r2 <- summary(fit)$adj.r.squared
mylabel = bquote(italic(R)^2 == .(format(r2, digits = 2)))
legend("bottomright", legend = mylabel ) # display legend
```

Adding both the R-squared value and *n* can be achieved in the following way (with credit to @DirkEddelbuettel here [How can I plot my R Squared value on my scatterplot using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761410/how-can-i-plot-my-r-squared-value-on-my-scatterplot-using-r))

```
legend("topleft", legend = c( paste("R2 =", format(r2, digits = 2)),
                              paste("n = ", nrow(DF)) ) )
```

However, I'm unable to find a way of modifying this to format the *R*^2 in a way that doesn't also paste the call. For example,

```
legend("topleft", legend = c( expression(paste(italic(R)^2, " = ", format(r2, digits = 2))),
                          paste("n = ", nrow(DF)) ) )
```

will successfuly format the *R*^2 but also pastes `format(r2, digits = 2)`

This seems as though it should be straightforward but I'm having no joy. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This might help you http://lukemiller.org/index.php/2012/10/adding-p-values-and-r-squared-values-to-a-plot-using-expression/.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20453408/4241780) for a possible duplicate of this question and workable answers.

Comment: Thank you both for bringing these solutions to my attention. Both work as desired, though the solution alluded to by @JWilliman is simpler and hence preferable. For completeness sake, that solution (by @SvenHohenstein) is `legend("bottomright", c(as.expression(bquote(italic(R)^2 == .(format(r2, digits = 2)))), as.expression(paste("n =", nrow(DF)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, using `atop` to split within several lines.

```
# your code
DF <- data.frame(VAR1=rnorm(100), VAR2=rnorm(100))
with(DF, plot(VAR1, VAR2))
fit <- lm(VAR2 ~ VAR1, data=DF)
r2 <- summary(fit)$adj.r.squared
mylabel = bquote(italic(R)^2 == .(format(r2, digits = 2)))

# the legend
legend("topright", legend=bquote(atop(italic(R)^2 == .(format(r2, digits = 2)),"n" == .(nrow(DF)))),bty="n")
```

Note that I had to remove the box around the legend (`bty=n"`) as it is not well managed.
For another solution involving `mtext` you may be interested in those two other post on stack and all links there:

[Expression and new line in plot labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549337/expression-and-new-line-in-plot-labels)

[Line break in expression()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237134/line-break-in-expression)

Comment: Thanks @Eric, this does the job, although not sure whether `atop` will permit multiple legend items (for the sake of versatility)